# How to disable all rows of HTML table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

[Not exactly the same as the question "how to disable knockout click...". My question involves specific usage of an HTML table and contains valuable approaches on solving such case.]

I have the following table and button below it:

```
<table>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: my-array">
<tr data-bind="click: $ShowDetails()">
...
<button>Add New Record</button>
```

The table rows are clickable (and would load some details data in another table).
On click of the button I need to disable all table rows and add one new `<tr>` on top.
I know how to add the new record on top:

```
$('<tr><td contenteditable="true">New Record Here</td></tr>').prependTo('table > tbody');
```

But how to disable all rows of the table so they won't be clickable and look disabled (grayed out)?

Comment: Add any overlaying element with background-color `black` and opacity `.5` over the table?!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable click event using Knockout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15244254/how-to-disable-click-event-using-knockout)

Comment: Thanks, A. Wolff. In this case I can't add the background-color over the entire table, as I need to have one row enabled. The one with the new record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `disabled` class to your `<tr>`'s using `$("tr").addClass("disabled")`.

The grayed out backgroung can be added by using `$('tr').css('background-color','grey')` or by describing `.disabled` class in your css-file:

```
tr.disabled {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

Then in your `ShowDetails()` method just check if calling element has the `.disabled` class by using `$(this).hasClass("disabled")` method. Show details if it doesn't and do nothing if it does.

Instead of checking the disabled class you can also add a new bool observable named `AddMode()` and set it to true on Add New button click, and on `ShowDetails()` put a first line `if(AddMode() === true) return;` (by @st_stefanov)

Comment: Something like this, yes. I will give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: instead of checking the disabled class I can also add a new bool observable named AddMode() and set it to true on Add New button click, and on ShowDetails() I will put a first line if(AddMode() === true) return;
What do you think?

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for your help FleGMan. I have chosen this as an answer, because it gave a full solution on all points I had in my question details. Welcome to the forum man and this is a good start for you here! Keep going this way! (Stan)

Answer (score 4):

I used this CSS code to disable HTML row

```
.row-disabled {
   background-color: rgba(236, 240, 241, 0.5);
   pointer-events: none;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function (){
     var myDisableBtn = $('#btn');
     myDisableBtn.on('click',function (){

       $('tr').css({'pointer-events':'none',
                    'background-color':'grey'});

     });
});
```

Comment: `disabled` property works on interactive element, which isn't a TR one

Comment: Thank you, did not know that

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btn').click(function () {
            $('#test_table tr').prop('disabled', 'disabled').css('background-color', 'grey');

            $('#test_table tbody').prepend('<tr><td contenteditable="true">New Record Here</td></tr>')
        });
    });


 <input type="button" id="btn" value="Add New Record"/>
    <table style="width:100%" id="test_table">
        <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
  </tr>
            </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Awesome, that works. Now I have to find a way to disable the click of the disabled rows as well....